# pubsub_v1 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'

Tags: python, importerror, google-cloud-pubsub

#### my version of python is 3.6.9

and I tried install many versions of google-cloud-pubsub
2.1.0
1.5.0
1.3.0 .....

but I still have problem import
"  "

the error message is
""" `from google.cloud import pubsub_v1`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-5ae969a9c485> in <module>
----> 1 from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\jb\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\__init__.py in <module>
     15 from __future__ import absolute_import
     16 
---> 17 from google.cloud.pubsub_v1 import types
     18 from google.cloud.pubsub_v1 import publisher
     19 from google.cloud.pubsub_v1 import subscriber

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\jb\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\pubsub_v1\types.py in <module>
     17 import sys
     18 
---> 19 from google.api import http_pb2
     20 from google.iam.v1 import iam_policy_pb2
     21 from google.iam.v1 import policy_pb2

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\jb\lib\site-packages\google\api\http_pb2.py in <module>
     33     syntax="proto3",
     34     serialized_options=b"\n\016com.google.apiB\tHttpProtoP\001ZAgoogle.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations;annotations\370\001\001\242\002\004GAPI",
---> 35     serialized_pb=b'\n\x15google/api/http.proto\x12\ngoogle.api"T\n\x04Http\x12#\n\x05rules\x18\x01 \x03(\x0b\x32\x14.google.api.HttpRule\x12\'\n\x1f\x66ully_decode_reserved_expansion\x18\x02 \x01(\x08"\x81\x02\n\x08HttpRule\x12\x10\n\x08selector\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\r\n\x03get\x18\x02 \x01(\tH\x00\x12\r\n\x03put\x18\x03 \x01(\tH\x00\x12\x0e\n\x04post\x18\x04 \x01(\tH\x00\x12\x10\n\x06\x64\x65lete\x18\x05 \x01(\tH\x00\x12\x0f\n\x05patch\x18\x06 \x01(\tH\x00\x12/\n\x06\x63ustom\x18\x08 \x01(\x0b\x32\x1d.google.api.CustomHttpPatternH\x00\x12\x0c\n\x04\x62ody\x18\x07 \x01(\t\x12\x15\n\rresponse_body\x18\x0c \x01(\t\x12\x31\n\x13\x61\x64\x64itional_bindings\x18\x0b \x03(\x0b\x32\x14.google.api.HttpRuleB\t\n\x07pattern"/\n\x11\x43ustomHttpPattern\x12\x0c\n\x04kind\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x0c\n\x04path\x18\x02 \x01(\tBj\n\x0e\x63om.google.apiB\tHttpProtoP\x01ZAgoogle.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/annotations;annotations\xf8\x01\x01\xa2\x02\x04GAPIb\x06proto3',
     36 )
     37 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'serialized_options'
"""
```

I tried change version of protobuf, but i could not solve this problem...
how to fix this issue???
Please help me...

Comment: I believe this can either be related to the protobuf known issue or a dependency conflict. I would suggest navigating through these two github pages [first](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/4716), [second](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3995) which have details on the known protobuf issue. There are several solutions posted, try them if they fit your use case. Alternatively create a fresh virtual environment and try to run your code again to address a possible dependency conflict.

Comment: Afterwards, if you are still finding the same issue please share a list of the dependencies you are using and which explicit workarounds have you tried so we can help you further.